# TypeError: x.pubkey.toBase58 is not a function

Tags: javascript, solana, solana-web3js

I am using `@solana/spl-token` library to create and mint tokens.
The `createMint()` function is throwing an error.

```
TypeError: x.pubkey.toBase58 is not a function
    at /home/denimcodes/Projects/solpay/node_modules/.pnpm/@solana+web3.js@1.66.2/node_modules/@solana/web3.js/lib/index.cjs.js:1565:23
    at Array.sort (<anonymous>)
    at Transaction.compileMessage (/home/denimcodes/Projects/solpay/node_modules/.pnpm/@solana+web3.js@1.66.2/node_modules/@solana/web3.js/lib/index.cjs.js:1553:17)
    at Transaction._compile (/home/denimcodes/Projects/solpay/node_modules/.pnpm/@solana+web3.js@1.66.2/node_modules/@solana/web3.js/lib/index.cjs.js:1660:26)
    at Transaction.sign (/home/denimcodes/Projects/solpay/node_modules/.pnpm/@solana+web3.js@1.66.2/node_modules/@solana/web3.js/lib/index.cjs.js:1765:26)
    at Connection.sendTransaction (/home/denimcodes/Projects/solpay/node_modules/.pnpm/@solana+web3.js@1.66.2/node_modules/@solana/web3.js/lib/index.cjs.js:6734:21)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async sendAndConfirmTransaction (/home/denimcodes/Projects/solpay/node_modules/.pnpm/@solana+web3.js@1.66.2/node_modules/@solana/web3.js/lib/index.cjs.js:2219:21)
    at async mintTo (file:///home/denimcodes/Projects/solpay/node_modules/.pnpm/@solana+spl-token@0.3.6_@solana+web3.js@1.66.2/node_modules/@solana/spl-token/lib/esm/actions/mintTo.js:23:12)
    at async file:///home/denimcodes/Projects/solpay/main.mjs:40:1
```

Here I have posted full code

```
import {
  getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount,
  mintTo,
  getAccount,
  getMint,
  createMint,
} from "@solana/spl-token";
import {
  Keypair,
  Connection,
  clusterApiUrl,
  LAMPORTS_PER_SOL,
} from "@solana/web3.js";

const payer = Keypair.generate();
const mintAuthority = payer;
const connection = new Connection(clusterApiUrl("devnet"), "confirmed");

const airdropSignature = await connection.requestAirdrop(
  payer.publicKey,
  LAMPORTS_PER_SOL
);
await connection.confirmTransaction(airdropSignature);

const mint = await createMint(
  connection,
  payer,
  mintAuthority.publicKey,
  mintAuthority.publicKey,
  9
);

const tokenAccount = await getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount(
  connection,
  payer,
  mint,
  mintAuthority.publicKey
);

await mintTo(
  connection,
  payer,
  mint,
  tokenAccount,
  mintAuthority,
  100 * (10 ^ 9)
);

const mintInfo = await getMint(connection, mint);
console.log(`Mint supply: ${mintInfo.supply}`);

const tokenAccountInfo = await getAccount(connection, tokenAccount);
console.log(`Token account amount: ${tokenAccountInfo.amount}`);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*x.pubkey.toBase58 is not a function* generally throws when one of the PublicKeys getting passed into an instruction (as a parameter, such as with mintTo) is either not an actual PublicKey or is a malformed PublicKey, as defined in [@solana/web3.js](https://solana-labs.github.io/solana-web3.js/classes/PublicKey.html).

In this case, you are passing in the response from getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount to the mintTo call, as seen below:

```
const **tokenAccount** = await *getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount*(
  connection,
  payer,
  mint,
  mintAuthority.publicKey
);

await mintTo(
  connection,
  payer,
  mint,
  **tokenAccount**,
  mintAuthority,
  100 * (10 ^ 9)
);
```

Your issue is that the response from [getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount](https://solana-labs.github.io/solana-program-library/token/js/modules.html#getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount) does not return just a PublicKey, but rather an [Account](https://solana-labs.github.io/solana-program-library/token/js/interfaces/Account.html). So therefore, token account is an invalid PublicKey object.

To fix this, you just need to dereference the token account address, like so

```
const **tokenAccount** = await *getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount*(
  connection,
  payer,
  mint,
  mintAuthority.publicKey
);

await mintTo(
  connection,
  payer,
  mint,
  **tokenAccount.address**,
  mintAuthority,
  100 * (10 ^ 9)
);
```

Good luck on your Solana journey :) If you want an extra challenge, create a single transaction that contains all of those instructions so that it completes atomically (Mint account created, token account created, and token minted all in one). You should be able to locate that information on the links provided.

Comment: Thank you so much. This has solved my issue and also made me understand more about the topic. I will definitely try to complete the challenge.